# How to sum all values based on match value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Question: How to sum all values based on matching values in a range?

(I would like to avoid using Pivot Table)

Hence, all "Volume" in Table 2 should be summed based on "dest_ctry" in Table 1.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple `SUMIF()` like-

```
=SUMIF(C5:C100,F5,D5:D100)
```

If your data in true table object then use-

```
=SUMIF(Table1[dest_ctry],[@Destination],Table1[Volume])
```